# How to pass xml linter config in code using Schemacrawler API

Tags: schemacrawler

Command-line schemacrawler has --linter-configs option, where we can pass xml config.
Is it possible to pass this linter-config.xml with schemacrawler API in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can build `LinterConfigs` completely programmatically - take a look at [`LintTest::lints`](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-lint/src/test/java/schemacrawler/test/LintTest.java#L74-L131), or read in an XML file - take a look at [`LintTest::runLintersWithConfig`](https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/blob/master/schemacrawler-lint/src/test/java/schemacrawler/test/LintTest.java#L190-L201)

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)